# Cloud Firestore - Date range query where documents have a date range

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, range

I want to make a date range query on a collection of objects which have multiple ranges. The exact use case is

- Each object represents a recurring event. The event can happen on multiple dates. So, consider the following:

  `object = {'inventoryOnDates': ['17-10-2019', '18-10-2019', '24-10-2019' ...]}`
- I have a calendar on client side, where a user can select a date range.
- Corresponding to this date range, I need to fetch all objects.

I was thinking about

1. Making the call for each entry of the selected date range, and handling aggregation on client side. The problem is that there would be a lot of reads as we will read the same listing object multiple times for the overlapped date range.
2. Try a service like elasticsearch/Algolia to due this operation

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there's no direct way to create this query.

Typically when I need to perform date range queries like that I end up storing less granular dates in the documents, such as the months (and/or weeks) that inventorying is happening. Then I can query for documents that have any inventory date that the user selected, and do the additional filtering client-side.

You may still need multiple queries, if the user selects multiple months (or weeks). But it's often a bit better than performing a separate query for each day in the range they selected.

Of course this all depends on the usage pattern. If your users typically select a few days, then using day granularity as you do now may be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As I understand, you are suggesting: that In my Firestore object, I store an objects at a less granular level, say week. This can be a new aggregated label. On the client side, for a given range, I get all objects for those corresponding weeks. The downside would be that if my inventory is at a day level, then each of my objects would be a bit more beefier and have information about all dates in the week. All additional filtering would be on client side.

Comment: That is correct. You'd store *additional* fields in your document at various granularity levels, and then do the final filtering client-side